# Single magazine issues with In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have some doubts about Newsstand/In-App Purchase that I really can not figure out. I'll try to be concise.

Scenario: magazine app that must offer the user the option to buy (in addition to subscriptions) a single issue. The issues will be released weekly, so even after the publication of the app.

My doubts (operational rather than technical) are related to how to deal with in-app purchases when the app has already been approved. How to manage the publication of future issues?
I thought it was enough to upload the new issues on my web service and then create a new product in the "In-App Purchase" section of iTunes Connect (because Apple says that individual magazine issues are non-consumable items), but how long will it take before the issue is on sale?

If in-app purchases (inserted after the app has already been approved) are subject to approval, it's almost impossible to meet deadlines of weekly publications...
How do apps (like Wired or various newspapers) sell individual issues?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anticipating future IAP products to make them approve, and activating them at the right time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i'm not understanding you question but you want to know how to release new issues of your magazine?

This might help:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf

Sorry if im wrong

EDit: also if you need help with the app itself apple created a video [here](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8266314619.08266314625.8367850245?i=1477723662)

Comment: My doubts are about In-App Purchase, how to sell weekly single issues on time using In-app Purchase?  
I could anticipate future IAP products and activate them at the right time.  
Is there another solution?

Comment: I am also having the same doubt and already wasted days in search of the solution. Please help me.

Comment: I'll be able to answer in the coming weeks.. ;)